# Use the same styles.css file for multiple Rmarkdown projects

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I have a styles.css file (which also refer to a logo png file) I use for my Rmarkdown documents that I'd like to be available to all my projects.   My current workflow is to copy it to each of my repo, but that also means I have to update all my repos when I want to make a change.

Any ideas?  Might be as simple as hosting it in a S3, but I'm not sure that rmarkdown allows that.

Comment: How are you "serving" your Rmd docs? Is it all local, where you can use an absolute file path on your local drive? If not, an S3 instance is overkill if you can place it somewhere on some website you control. The files don't have to be linked to by anything on that particular website (and subdir).

Comment: I just knit them locally as self contained and email them.

It is used by multiple persons who don't necessarily have a common place where we could save it  on the network.  


Maybe in an R package?

Comment: Okay, so I suggest you create a fixed directory somewhere and reference files in it from each of your apps. When you update the CSS files in that one directory, all reports that use it will from then-on see the newer versions. You might want to version the CSS, either or both of: version-control (e.g., `git`, `svn`), versioned files (e.g., `/some/path/styles1.css`), or versioned directories (e.g., `/some/path/v1/styles.css`) if you need reproducibility.

Comment: thanks that makes sense -- I made an edit while you were typing.   We are multiple users and we dont have a shared network  space where everyone have access, except maybe bitbucket.

There must be a way for rmarkdown to read the styles.css on a website/bitbucket public  repo, I'll investigate that

thanks for chiming in :)

Comment: The visible web space doesn't need to be a "proper web server" to be effective. For instance, if you have an account on github or gitlab, you can serve files from a repo there. (And that would address my version-control comment above :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with bitbucket specifics, but ... https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/raw/master/data-raw/diamonds.csv (big link) is a CSV file under version control in a repo on github, and I can download it just fine. That works equally well for CSS or other types of files. This likely works best if (1) your connection to the bitbucket instance is relatively fast, and (2) it does not require authentication. If #2 is a problem, you might consider API keys (if supported) to automate downloads.

Comment: sounds good - thanks
I wasnt aware you could refer to a local file outside the Rproj directory, so that's good to know